# Sqoop job incremental import using free form query

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to do sqoop job incremental import using free form query. Here's the query being used

```
sqoop job --create importjobinl -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username training --password training --query 'select id,name,unix_timestamp(time_updated) from intest where $CONDITIONS' --target-dir /user/new/lll/`date +%d%T|sed 's/://g'` -m 1 --check-column time_updated --incremental append  --last-value '1441526438'
```

The job is not getting created It shows.

```
Incremental imports require a table.
Try --help for usage instructions.
```

It works when I use `--table` intest instead of `--query`, but I want to use `--query` to convert date to epochtime using unix_timestamp since the value in mysql table intest is in yyyy-mm-dd format

Version used :Sqoop 1.2.0-cdh3u0

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop incremental imports for free form queries was added from Sqoop 1.4.2
JIRA link : [Sqoop Incremental import Support for free form queries](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-444)

Since you are using Sqoop 1.2.0, this feature might not be available for you to use

Answer (score 0):

1. Do an initial pull using sqoop.
2. Make sure the date format of your column is in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS if you are using the last modified column as date.
3. Run below statement for incremental load to your hive table which includes free from query.

   `sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username training --password training --query "select * from intest where $CONDITIONS"  --hive-import --hive-table db_name_x.table_name_x --incremental lastmodified -check-column date_x --target-dir /user/xyz -m 1`